# Talend: Save variable for later use

Tags: etl, talend

I´m trying to save a value in spreadsheet's header for later use as a new column value.

This is the reduced version with value (XYZ) in header:

[image: original report]

The value in header must be used for new column CODE:
[image]

This is my design:

[image]

tFilterRow_1 is used to reject rows without values in A, B, C columns. 
There is a conditional in tJavaRow_1 to set a global variable:

```
if(String.valueOf(row1.col_a).equals("CODE:")){
  globalMap.putIfAbsent("code", row1.col_b);
}
```

The Var expression in tMap_1 to get the global variable is:

```
(String)globalMap.get("code")
```

The Var "code" is mapped to column "code" but I'm getting this output:

```
a1|b1|c1|
a2|b2|c2|
a3|b3|c3|
```

What is missed or there is a better approach to accomplish this escenario ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:
I tJavaRow use the input_row or the actual rowN in this case row4.

Longer answer, how I'd do it.

I'd do is let the excel flow in AS-IS. By using some Java tricks we can simply skip the first few rows then let the rest of the flow go through. 
So the filter + tjavarow combo can be replaced with a tJavaFlex.

tJavaFlex I'd do:

begin:

```
boolean contentFound = false;
```

main

```
if(input_row.col1 != null && input_row.col1.equalsIgnoreCase("Code:") ) {
   globalMap.put("code",input_row.col2);
}
if(input_row.col1 != null && input_row.col1.equalsIgnoreCase("Column A:") ) {
   contentFound = true;
} else {
   if(false == contentFound) continue;
}
```

This way you'll simply skip the first few records (i.e header) and only care about the actual data.

Comment: I found my (silly) error, the columns were combined in the original xlsx file,   then conditions on tFilterRow had reference to wrong columns. I just test your approach and works perfectly, Thanks!.